# Risk Strategies

Tags: risk

Hey everyone I like Risk and play it a lot. But I always see the same strats, take a small continent like australia and slow push. The other option I have been seeing is take territories in a large continent and then expand quickly with overwhelming number quickly.

My issue is that these all have they're own issues. For instance when you turtle and slow push with Australia but can be cornered and ganged up on. So I am wondering if there are any other strategies possible and if there are, I would love to hear them.